# How to run a Django method in parallel with Celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a method `update_prices()` on my model I would like to run in parallel with Celery but I can't figure out how to make it works. As you can see there is a problem with the `.s()` because it complains with `'function' object has no attribute 's'`. How can i do that?

This is my code:

```
@celery.app.task(name='Update')
def update():

    # list of arguments
    exchanges_list = Exchange.objects.filter(status='ok').values_list('name', flat=True)

    # the function that execute the method
    def update_prices(name):
        Exchange.objects.get(name=name).update_prices()

    gp = group([update_prices.s(name) for name in exchanges_list])()
```

A slightly different approach generates the same error:

```
gp = group(update_prices.s(name) for ex in exchanges_list)()
gp = group(update_prices.(name).s() for ex in exchanges_list)()
gp = group(Exchange.objects.get(name=name).update_prices().s() for ex in exchanges_list)()
```

This is very similar to the example in the [Celery documention](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#groups) for simple group task:

```
res = group(add.s(i, i) for i in range(10))()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reply to my question because I finally found what was causing the error. The method `update_prices(name)` needed a dedicated decorator like this and it works like a charm!

```
@celery.app.task
def update_prices(name):
        Exchange.objects.get(name=name).update_prices()
```